# lsync, unison or some other inotify auto-syncing tool..?

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, inotify, unison

I have an app farm which generates thumbnails and makes them available to a web server farm using nfs. However the performance is so poor so I am going to make a local copy of the files on each web node.

I looked at unison and lsync, but there doesn't seem to be a rpm available from the centOS5.5 repo for either.

which one should I use, or some other strategy. I critically need the sync to be immediate as the user needs to display the thumbnail straight away on a web page, so inotify based tools are good!

Edit: when I say immediate, I mean pushed out rather than pulled on some schedule.

In the end, lsync have released some more versions so I used that, and lsync works well once it is running (ie syncs in a few seconds) however it needs to enumerate each directory beforehand and for a very large file-system takes many hours..

Answer (score 1):

> I critically need the sync to be immediate as the user needs to display the thumbnail straight away on a web page

So you've no control over server affinity in your load balancing? Time to get a new load balancer.

> I looked at unison and lsync, but there doesn't seem to be a rpm available from the centOS5.5 repo for either.

Previously I did this by building replication into the application - after all, it's the first thing to know when new content needs to be replicated - it was just a few lines of PHP to publish a notice to the other nodes that content needed fetching - when a node has been offline for a while, I ran rsync before bringing it completely back online (this approach makes handling offline nodes much simpler and non-intrusive). However if I were to implement such a system today then I do it using overlay filesystems - perhaps an NFS at the bottom of the stack and copy up on access.

See also [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/156215/please-help-to-find-a-solution-for-two-way-real-time-synchronization-on-centos-5/156270)

HTH

C.

Comment: well the idea thing would be to build something into the app, and preferably better design the nfs layout. but thats not possible at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything for it in the repository, but you might find that [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) may be helpful.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.
incron is not recursive. though it looks kinda cool and i will be messing with it for fun at some later date.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed unison version 2.32.52 on a one of my CentOS 5.x boxes.

With unison its important to note that **all** servers that will be synchronizing together will need to be running the exact same version. Unison won't work when linked to other unison versions older and newer.

For myself I found that this rpm http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el5/x86_64/unison-2.32.52-1.el5.rf.x86_64.html worked for me running on centos 5.8

As for lsync I wouldn't be able to tell you much about it as I have never personally used it. 
I can however say that Unison when used properly is a fantastic tool.

You can set Unison on a crontab to check for changes every 1-10 minutes.

Comment: Unison now has a `repeat=watch` option to monitor file changes.